# How to split the interface passed to the method

Tags: go, telegram

I use this library [tucnak/telebot](https://github.com/tucnak/telebot) to build a telegram bot.

Method `b.Handle()` have two parameters such as [`Handle(endpoint interface{}, handler` interface{})`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2#Bot.Handle).

Here is the code i use for a starter

```
func main() {
    b, err := tb.NewBot(tb.Settings{
        Token:  "TOKEN_HERE",
        Poller: &tb.LongPoller{Timeout: 10 * time.Second},
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    // i want to split this(interface)
    b.Handle("/hello", func(m *tb.Message) {
        b.Send(m.Sender, "Hello World!")
    })

    b.Start()
}
```

Here is what I have tried to compile :

```
func main() {
    b, err := tb.NewBot(tb.Settings{
        Token:  "TOKEN_HERE",
        Poller: &tb.LongPoller{Timeout: 10 * time.Second},
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
                    
    b.Handle("/hello", handleHello(b))

    b.Start()
}

func handleHello(b *tb.Bot) {
        b.Send(m.Sender, "Hello World!")
}
```

I have an error with this code : `undefined m`, in `m.Sender()` and I can't use `m` as a parameter for that function call, because of the same error. I don't understand where that `m` comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bot responsibility is to listen some sockets, whatever, and calls your `function handlers` when a message arrives on the associated `path handler`.

Thus, you should not try to call your handlers like in `b.Handle("/hello", handleHello(b))`. Instead pass the function handler to the bot `b.Handle("/hello", handleHello)`. Let the bot call that function with the new message as a parameter like in `func(m *tb.Message)`.

To retain a reference to `b`, you can proceed as described by  [Sinan Coment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69334371/4466350). Write a function that takes in parameter the bot and returns a function that receives the message as a parameter.

The bot instance `b` acts as a [muxer](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux), you can re use that terminology to improve the meaning of your code.

A muxer is defined as `[...] a request multiplexer. It matches the URL of each incoming request against a list of registered patterns and calls the handler for the pattern that most closely matches the URL.`

Though, I want to suggest you to wrap that instance of [telebot.Bot](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2#Bot) into a type that defines message handlers as methods.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    tb "gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2"
)

func main() {
    mux, err := tb.NewBot(tb.Settings{
        Token:  "TOKEN_HERE",
        Poller: &tb.LongPoller{Timeout: 10 * time.Second},
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    bot := botHandlers{Bot: mux}

    mux.Handle("/hello", bot.handleHello)

    mux.Start()
}

type botHandlers struct {
    *tb.Bot
}

func (b botHandlers) handleHello(m *tb.Message) {
    b.Send(m.Sender, "Hello World!")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6ng6WSIp8Er

Comment: How i can stop a `handleHello`? But command `/hello` should work

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/wtT3zpC31ui I am writing a bot for expenses. But i can't stop a last handler i have 2 folded handler into handler. Other commands works, but category continues change if i send message. Maybe you have a good example of branch bot?

Comment: @gelerum those questions go way beyond your initial post. And the subject is completely different. It is about understanding and managing states of multiple clients consuming the same endpoint. This is a topic by itself. .... But, dont do as you demonstrated, you are attacking the problem with a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see hello handler takes a parameter called m here.

```
b.Handle("/hello", func(m *tb.Message) {
```

so you should return a function that takes the same parameter.

```
func handleHello(b *tb.Bot) func(m *tb.Message) {
    return func(m *tb.Message) {
        b.Send(m.Sender, "Hello World!")
    }
}
```